# Write a String Message to Remote Server Using Socket in Android

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to write a simple message to a remote Server using Socket in Android, The remote server was provided to me, here is my attempt, it stops at `out.write`

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String comment = params[0];
    Log.i(TAG_STRING, "Comment is " + comment);
    String response = null;
    Socket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = new Socket("www.regisscis.net", 8080);
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        Log.i(TAG_STRING, "Calling Write");
        out.writeBytes(comment);
        out.flush();
        String resposeFromServer = in.readUTF();
        out.close();
        in.close();
        response = resposeFromServer;               
        socket.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}
```

Would anyone know what I am doing wrong,

Comment: 8080 thats the HTTP port so you need to send an HTTP request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that I to use `out.println("message")` instead of `out.write("message")` when I post to this server. So I have updated my method like so

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String comment = params[0];
    String response = null;
    Socket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = new Socket("www.regisscis.net", 8080);
        if (socket.isConnected()) {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            Log.i(TAG_STRING, "Calling Write");
            out.println(comment);
            String resposeFromServer = in.readLine();
            out.close();
            in.close();
            response = resposeFromServer;               
            socket.close();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG_STRING, "Socket is not connected");
        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}
```